# Want to get value from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Here, I am getting value in javaScript ajax as an array.
I want only value from an array.
My array is like,

```
data:

monthArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => abc
            [total_point] => 100
            [total_earn_point] => 0
        )

)
weekArray
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => xyz
            [total_point] => 100
            [total_earn_point] => 0
        )

)
```

Here,

```
function emp_perf(){

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grade_tasks/emp_performance",
                data:'',
                type:"GET",
                success:function(data){

                    alert(data[0]);

                },
                error:function (){}
                });
                }
               setInterval(emp_perf, 3000);
```

Here, I could not fetch.
I want data as, separate in javascript variable.

So, how can this be done in javascript?
**(Updated)**

Comment: Can you show us the `data` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data){

   // Both the below method works.
   alert(data["monthArray"][0].name); // will alert abc
   alert(data["monthArray"][0]["total_point"]); // will alert 100

   // Loop through data[0]
   for(var i in data["monthArray"][0]){
    alert(data["monthArray"][0][i]); 
   }

},
```

**Explaination:**

Your data is an object, so you can access its elements using the key. `data.monthName` or `data["monthName"]`, now `data.monthName` is an array and you can access it's values using `[]` whose first element is an object again use same notation to fetch its values.

Comment: @RayonDabre why do you doubt that?

Comment: I am getting "undefined" as result in "alert(data[0]["total_point"]);"

Comment: I suppose `data` is not an array but an `object` and you might have to consider the keys as well..

Comment: @RayonDabre yeah you right, my bad. see the updated code.

Comment: I am getting an error in console like this,

TypeError: data.monthArray is undefined
 

alert(data["monthArray"][0].name);

Comment: It seems like it isn't clear if the nested structure is an array containing an object or vice versa.

I'd recommend just iterating either the array indices or object keys using this syntax:
for (var key in data){ 
  console.log('data[' + key + ']: ' + data[key]);
}
 
You could even through in a typeof in there for good measure (so you can determine when it is an array or an object).  Not sure what format that data is in - but it looks suspiciously like that top level might be functions.

Answer (score 0):

Return the data as JSON, is the best way to interact between PHP & Javascript. Then you can use `JSON.parse` to convert the JSON to a javascript object/array.

**PHP**

```
<?php
//emp_performance
die(json_encode($dataArray));
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
function emp_perf(){

   jQuery.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>grade_tasks/emp_performance",
       data:'',
       type:"GET",
       success:function(data){

        data = JSON.parse(data);
        //you can use $.parseJSON(data) too since you are using jQuery

        console.log(data.MonthArray);
        console.log(data.MonthArray[0].Name);
        console.log(data.MonthArray[0].total_point);
        console.log(data.MonthArray[0].total_earn_point);

            console.log(data.WeekArray);
        console.log(data.WeekArray[0].Name);
        console.log(data.WeekArray[0].total_point);
        console.log(data.WeekArray[0].total_earn_point);

        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}
setInterval(emp_perf, 3000);
```